# For loop ignoring consecutive values

Tags: python

I've got the following simple for loop.

```
for word in text:
    if word in stopword_list:
       text.remove(word)
```

So far it has worked for removing any item found on the stopword_list. However if two of these items are next to each other, it ignores the second. For example:

`stopword_list = (['i', 'am'])`

`'i'` or `'am'` individually will be removed

`(['I', 'x', 'y', 'am'])` will remove both `'I'` and `'am'`

`(['I', 'am'])` will remove `'I'` but not `'am'`

If I run the list itself through the loop, it removes every other word.

Why is this happening?

Comment: "Why is this happening?" - because you're modifying the same collection you're currently iterating. A classic mistake in many environments.

Comment: If you create another instance of the list and use one to iterate and another one to remove, then you will not have such problems.

Comment: Try a list comprehension [ word for word in text if word not in stopword_list ]